# Some localStorage items are not being displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have 5 items in localStorage, however, when I try to output all the files,

only 2 items are being output, and not all.

JS that puts into localStorage:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.SaveToCart = function (id, iName, iAlbum, iPrice) {
        var quantity = 0;
        if (localStorage.getItem('Product_' + id) === null) {
            quantity = 1;
        } else {
            var tempItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Product_' + id));
            var tempQuantity = parseInt(tempItem['quantity']);
            quantity = tempQuantity + 1;
        }
        var cartItem = {
            'quantity': quantity,
            'name': iName,
            'album': iAlbum,
            'price': iPrice
        }
        localStorage.setItem('Product_' + id, JSON.stringify(cartItem));
    };
```

Cart JS:

```
function ShoppingCart() {

    var output;
    var productName;
    var productAlbum;
    var productQuantity;
    var productPrice;
    var productSubTotal = 0;
    var totalPrice;


    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length - 1; i++) {
        var keyName = localStorage.key(i);
        if (keyName.indexOf('Product_') == 0) {
            var product = localStorage.getItem(keyName);

            var product = localStorage.getItem('Product_' + i);

            var result = JSON.parse(product);

            totalPrice = 0;
            productName = result.name
            productAlbum = result.album;
            productQuantity = parseInt(result.quantity);
            productPrice = parseFloat(result.price).toFixed(2);
            productSubTotal = parseInt(productQuantity) * parseFloat(productPrice).toFixed(2);

            outputName = "<div id='cart-table'><table><tr><td><b>NAME: </b>" + productName + "</td></tr></div>";
            outputAlbum = "<tr><td><b>ALBUM: </b>" + productAlbum + "</td></tr>";
            outputQuantity = "<tr><td><b>QUANTITY: </b>" + productQuantity + "</td></tr>";
            outputPrice = "<tr><td><b>PRICE: </b> EUR " + productPrice + "</td></tr>";
            outputSubTotal = "<tr><td><b>SUB-TOTAL: </b> EUR " + productSubTotal + "</td></tr></table><br><br>";


            var TotalOutput = outputName + outputAlbum + outputQuantity + outputPrice + outputSubTotal;

            document.getElementById("Cart-Contents").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Cart-Contents").innerHTML + TotalOutput;
            totalPrice += parseFloat(totalPrice) + parseFloat(productSubTotal);
            productSubTotal = productSubTotal + productSubTotal;
        }
        i++;


    }
    totalPrice = productSubTotal;

    localStorage.setItem("price", totalPrice);

    var outputTotal = "<br><br><h1><table><tr><td><b>TOTAL:</b> EUR " + totalPrice + "</td></tr></table></h1>";
    document.getElementById("total-price").innerHTML = document.getElementById("total-price").innerHTML + outputTotal;


}

function ClearCart() {

    localStorage.clear();
    document.location.reload(true);

}

window.onload = ShoppingCart;

    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Cart-Contents"></div>
<div id="total-price"></div>
```

Also, I have another problem, the Total Price is not getting calculated correctly. I am getting  28.12 as a total of 14.06 + 16.40. WHy is this happening?

To give you an idea:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CPbO.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk6kC.png

Comment: Can you add a fiddle for this?

Comment: Change your `for` loop to this: `for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){` - I'm not sure why you had `localStorage.length - 1`

Comment: Why those two separate lines in the loop to initialize the "product" variable?

Comment: If you format your code properly, others will find it easier to read and understand it.

Comment: @DrColossos 
http://jsfiddle.net/cgwrp/

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop to this: `for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){`.

And don't add `i++;` to the end of your loop's body.

Both would cause your loop to not hit all items, for different reasons.

Comment: I still get 2 maximum items displayed and not all the items in the localStorage

Comment: Check what `localStorage.length` is before you loop it

Comment: It is 5. `alert(localStorage.length);`

Comment: @JustAJDoe And why do you have 2 `var product = ` lines?

Comment: one gets the key and the other gets the items in the localSotrage